# How to include javascript libraries in Visual Studio TypeScript build

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to make the built-in "TypeScript Build" in Visual Studio 2017 include javascript libraries as well as all of my TypeScript files in the transpiled bundle.js output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only solution is to rename the javascript library files (.js) to typescript files (.ts)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than an actual solution, but what I do is write my own definition files for non-TypeScript code that I know I'll be using. It could be as simple as

```
declare var $: any;
```

for something like jQuery, if you don't mind the lack of type checking.

Comment: I was asking about the actual javascript code files and not the typescript definitions.